# A $5\times 5$ grid of single-digit numbers in $\mathbb N$, with one cell empty. What number should be in the cell?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

> **16**.$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> 2 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 5
> \\\hline
> 7 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 4
> \\\hline
> 1 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 6
> \\\hline
> 2 & 4 & 5 & 4 & \mathbf{?}
> \\\hline
> 8 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 5
> \\\hline
> \end{array} $$
>
> Is the answer 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5?
>
> <sub>[Photograph of the problem source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRQUD.png)</sub>

Really I don't understand. How does such a question relate to logic? For me, it's a game about numbers.Not Logic. It really annoys me to solve such a question. Anyway, I took 12 minutes for this question in exam. I came home. I could not even "solve" it at home ether. I think, such a question is nonsense. No science has anything to do with it. Please help me with the question and please explain me, what does it really mean to solve such a question?

Comment: This kind of puzzle is supposed to test both your intuition and how far and fast your brain can go testing many complex assumptions from scratch. Many 'math' jobs relate to this problem solving ability. I personally think that with practice those exercises become irrelevant. And without practice you need luck to find the right assumption to test (symmetry, rotation, rules or other  basic operations applying on rows / columns or diagonal) It is usually a combination of multiples rules

Comment: If it's any consolation, the answer isn't jumping out at me, either.

Comment: The answer isn't jumping out at me either. Do you have a context or previous questions that could help?

Comment: and which class are you studying in? So we can get an idea of the level of techniques we can try. I mean anything other than basic arithmetic

Comment: In our country, the examination that must be entered to study the Master. (Stage 1)

Comment: @amWhy I am grateful that you improve the question's title

Comment: @Learner As Max Ft suggested, can you put some similar question from the exam ? It might help understanding the approach

Comment: I am going to say "9 should go in there because all other numbers are in the grid elsewhere and it isn't fair that 9 is overlooked".  I challenge you find *any* statement that says that reason is wrong.

Comment: @idpd15 /Max Ft I'll do it gladly. But I can not add pictures to the comment..

Comment: @fleablood true, but it's obvious Blue's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> $$\begin{array}{c}
> x \\
> y \\
> p \\
> q \\
> r
> \end{array} \qquad\to\qquad x^y = pqr\quad\text{(concatenated)} $$

---

*"[W]hat does it really mean to solve such a question?"*

Well, such a question challenges us to find order amid chaos. That's what mathematics ---as the study of *pattern*--- is all about, so it's not a completely irrelevant mental exercise. As others mention, it could be instructive to find ways to justify *any* answer. (It's always possible to do that in a puzzle like this one, although not all rules are particularly "nice" ... but "nice" is subjective and not actually required.)

That said, this kind of thing is a *horrible* exercise for an exam. Not only is it unreasonable to expect someone to notice *any* pattern in a fixed time-frame, it is unreasonably-unreasonable to expect someone to notice the (so-called) "correct" pattern *at all*, since that's often akin to mind-reading. ("What was the author thinking?")

In any case, here's a walk-through of my thought process: After a minute or so of skimming the grid, and just before abandoning the whole thing, I *happened* to recognize the powers "27", "128", and "256" amid the columns of digits; then ---oh, yeah!--- "243" and "343" (which aren't always on the tip of my brain); and then ---hey!--- that could be "625" in the last column! I must be onto something! Yet ... "73" and "44" and friends aren't powers, so maybe "27" was a red herring. Then, the "aha!" moment: $2^7 = 128$. Done.

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: Wow. Just ... wow.

Answer (score 2):

> No science has anything to do with it.

I must say I agree. This question is, mathematically speaking, nonsense: for *any* of the possible "answers" $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ you could easily cook up a function $f(i,j)$ that computes the correct value in all cells $(i,j)$.

Of course what is *meant* is for you to find a "simple" function that produces the numbers shown, where one person's "simple" might include rules like "count the number of letters in the English spelling of the number to produce the next entry" which might not be considered simple at all by somebody else.

To make the question precise, one would need to provide an expression grammar, and ask, for instance, for the expression tree of least depth that can produce all provided inputs, which can then be evaluated on the empty cell. As the question stands, it is ill-posed, a quantitatively-flavored brainteaser at best (with very little relation to mathematics), and IMO quite a poor question to ask on any kind of entrance examination intended to gauge mathematical ability.

Comment: "which might not be considered simple at all by somebody else." If the answer is intended to be blues answer that the answer is 2 because $5^4 = 625$, then this *utterly* fails as an acceptable "simple" rule.

Answer (score 2):

Such problems are set up by people who have not the slightest idea of mathematics, but make a lot of money from their tests.

It is alright to create problems where some sort of "mathematical pattern recognition" is required, but such problems are infinitely more structure hiding and revealing than this idiotic example. Such problems (in disguise) might appear at the IMOs.

For the problem at hand find for each option A) – E) a formula containing only the most basic operations (as the test creator does not even know how to add fractions) that creates this value. Then using Ocam's razor choose the shortest of these.

Comment: Please see Blue's answer. It's a puzzle problem.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: The solution is indeed perfect. I was afraid that the problem would involve decimal expansion in some way – a clear symptom of an uninteresting question.

Comment: The fact that it was a puzzle does not make these observations any less valid.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation of such tests is they cannot check what logic was actually used. For example, Blue's method looks convincing, however one might add all numbers $(98)$ and think it is $2$ short to a hundred.

Comment: *"2 short to a hundred"?* Don't you mean "3 short to the first 3-digit prime"? :)

Comment: @Blue, I meant if one answers $2$ based on the logic the numbers must add up to $100$, then he would score the same mark though with much weaker logic, a fuzzy logic.

Comment: I understand. I was just taking the opportunity to show that it's possible to find even-fuzzier logic to justify another answer. BTW: I like your approach. It would've been a nice coincidence if your sum of (numbers-in-)squares idea had led to an unambiguous sum-of-squares. :)

Comment: @Blue. Thanks. +1 to your approach and presentation of solid/sound logic.